# Access local dataframe outside the function in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I created a function that will fill a data frame but I forgot to write `return df1` at the end of the function. and the script takes too long to finish. so it's not feasible to rerun it again.

the function does something like that:

> df <- function(df1){
>
> .... some operations on df1
>
> return df1
>
> }

Is there any way that I can access this dataframe from inside the function and then apply more tests on it normally as a global one?

Maybe something like this: `myfunc.df1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to 'break-into' a running R process like that. If your script has already finished, the objects not `returned` are discarded, and thus no longer accessible. Always test your scripts on small datasets if your script takes weeks to finish...

Comment: the script is already finished, and i did not returned any objects, so i need to rerun it again .. :(\

Comment: However sad that is, you need to rerun your script.